# Customized deleting files from a folder

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder where different files can be located. I would like to check if it contains other files than .gitkeep and delete them, keeping .gitkeep at once. How can I do this ? (I'm a newbie when it comes to bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, there are multiple ways to do this, I am just sharing what little I know of linux :

```
1)find <path-to-the-folder> -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -iname '\.gitkeep' -delete
```

maxdepth of 1 specifies to search only the current directory. If you remove maxdepth, it will recursively find all files other than '.gitkeep' in all directories under your path. You can increase maxdepth to however deep you want find to go into directories from your path.

'-type f' specifies that we are just looking for files . If you want to find directories as well (or links, other types ) then you can omit this option.

-iname '.gitkeep'  specifies a case insensitive math for '.gitkeep', the '\' is used for escaping the '.', since in bash, '.' is a regular expression.
You can leave it to be -name instead of -iname for case sensitive match.

The '!' before -iname, is to do an inverse match, i.e to find all files that don't have the name '.gitkeep', if you remove the '!', then you will get all files that match '.gitkeep'.

finally, '-delete' will delete the files that match this specification.

If you want to see what all files will be deleted before executing -delete, you can remove that flag and it will show you all the files :

```
find <path-to-the-folder> -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -iname '\.gitkeep'
```

(you can also use -print at the end, which is just redundant)

```
2) for i in `ls -a | grep -v '\.gitkeep'` ; do rm -rf $i ; done
```

Not really recommended to do it this way, since rm -rf is always a bad idea (IMO). You can change that to rm -f (to ensure it just works on file and not directories).

To be on the safe side, it is recommended to do an echo of the file list first to see if you are ready to delete all the files shown :

```
for i in `ls -a | grep -v '\.gitkeep'` ; do echo $i ; done
```

This will iterate thru all the files that don't match '.gitkeep' and delete them one by one ... not the best way I suppose to delete files

```
3)rm -rf $(ls -a  | grep -v '\.gitkeep')
```

Again, careful with rm -rf, instead of rm -rf above, you can again do an echo to find out the files that will get deleted

I am sure there are more ways, but just a glimpse of the array of possibilities :)

Good Luck,

Ash

================================================================

EDIT :

=> manpages are your friend when you are trying to learn something new, if you don't understand how a command works or what options it can take and do, always lookup man for details.

ex : man find

=> I understand that you are trying to learn something out of your comfort zone, which is always commendable, but stack overflow doesn't like people asking questions without researching.

If you did research,  you are expected to mention it in your question, letting people know what you have done to find answers on your own.

A simple google search or a deep dive into stack overflow questions would have provided you with a similar or even a better answer to your question. So be careful :)

Forewarned is forearmed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use find:

```
find /path/to/folder -maxdepth 1 ! -name .gitkeep -delete
```